# event.object.lastVisionImage.getBitmap is not a function

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, firebase-mlkit

I am doing a small project on Nativescript, using the ML kit for face recognition

My task is to take a photograph after a face has been recognized. On Android, this function works fine and the image is saved, but on iOS, an error occurs.

Tell me, what could be the problem and how to solve it?

```
const bmp = event.object.lastVisionImage.getBitmap();
const source = new ImageSource();
source.setNativeSource(bmp);

var imageData = source.toBase64String("jpeg");
```

> 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: TypeError:
> event.object.lastVisionImage.getBitmap is not a function. (In
> 'event.object.lastVisionImage.getBitmap()',
> 'event.object.lastVisionImage.getBitmap' is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Does this come from this unofficial plug-in?
https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-plugin-firebase-mlkit-unofficial

I'm afraid MLKit team doesn't officially support the NativeScript plugin, posting the question in the community of the plugin provider might get an answer more efficiently. Thanks!